# Date conditional for over test if over 2 years

Tags: conditionals, date, time

Haven't used EE in a while and having a brain freeze on best way to do a date conditional.

I have a date custom field for a DOB. I want to conditional show items if the person/child is over 2 years old.

I'm thinking something along the line of:

```
{if ("{current_time format='%U'}" - "{child_dob format='%U'}") > '63113904'  }
    Do this
{if:else}
    Do that
{/if}
```

Where this would test against the Unix timestamp? Or am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but no bracing and formatting is needed; date variables will output timestamps without formatting, and comparisons can be made properly between integer types. So you can use a simpler:

```
{if (current_time - child_dob) >= 63072000}
    Do this
{if:else}
    Do That
{/if}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a test in the morning!

Comment: Just testing this at the moment, doesn't seem to be working, although am I right in thinking that EE doesn't do maths in the template out of the box?

Comment: Math in conditionals is available since [version 2.9.0 in July of 2014](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/about/changelog.html#version-2-9-0).

Comment: Ah, that's why. We're on an earlier version. Used a maths plugin and seems to be working ok now. Thanks!

Comment: Time to upgrade! ;)