# Comparing custom member field with current date

Tags: custom-fields

I have a member field [cb1_expire] that I am using to store the expiration date in the user profile.  The format that will be put into the field will always be "mm/dd/yyyy". (field type is text)
I want to compare this field with the current date to see if the current date is past the expiration date so that I can perform a specific action and inform the user that is access is expired.
So far I have not been able to render the custom field in a format that I can test with the current date.

Is this possible and if so how can I accomplish this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Anthony Jaxon, Los Angeles, CA USA

Comment: This may help too : http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/37782/166

Comment: I've tried the following methods to get my custom field containing 
"01/23/1998" to any format I can use to compare with the current date.  None of these methods work.

Comment: {if "{cb1_expire format='%U'}" < "{current_time format='%U'}"}

  date has expired

 {/if}

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,
If you cant convert your field to a date field, you're going to have build a plugin using php strtotime function or use something like this [from Rye](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rye-date)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by comparing the dates in a "yyyymmdd" format.  The issue seems to be that custom member fields can only be set to text format and so I was never able to convert it to UNIX format.
So I am entering the dates in the custom member field (cb1_expire) as 20151201.  Then I format the current_time to the same format and then compare them.

{if '{current_time format='%Y%m%d'}' > cb1_expire}

If the formatted current_time is greater than cb1_expire, I know the expiration date has passed.

Hope this helps someone....